# Could not find specified column in results in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am getting following error while executing simple select statement in my custom code.
**Could not find specified column in results**

Here is my code-

```
string queryBuilder="select BASKET_DESCRIPTION from MARKET_BASKET_REQUESTS order by BASKET_DESCRIPTION limit 1";
 public T SelectSingle<T>(string queryBuilder) where T : new()//made new
        {
            T result = new T();
            TableScheme dbTable = GetTableSchemeFromType(typeof(T));
            IDataReader reader = ExecuteReader(queryBuilder); 
            result = ParseDataReaderToEntityListtttt<T>(reader,dbTable);
            reader.Close();
            return result;
        }
        private T ParseDataReaderToEntityListtttt<T>(IDataReader reader, TableScheme dbTable) where T : new()
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
           T result = new T();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                T t = new T();
                foreach (var column in dbTable.Columns)
                {
                    type.GetProperty(column.AssociatedPropertyName).SetValue(t, reader[column.ColumnName], null);
                }
                result = t;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: What is the code of GetTableSchemeFromType? Which line of code gives you error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SELECT` statement only selects the `BASKET_DESCRIPTION` column, while your `TableScheme` (which is generated by the not shown method `GetTableSchemeFromType()`, but I guess it uses `Type.GetProperties()` to get all properties) is requesting other columns by name which aren't present in the result set, which is what the error is trying to tell you.

So either `SELECT *` (or at least all relevant columns), or stop building your own ORM and use an existing one.

Comment: Exact Answer. Thanks